# Chrome blocks the blob object and shows the downloaded file is dangerous

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, blob

I am downloading the file from server and then in angular after receiving the response I am using the blob to download the file. The file is of type tar.gz But google chrome browser is showing warning as 'xyz.tar.gz is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous' and sometimes it also shows that 'xyz.tar.gz may be dangerous, so Chrome has blocked it'. I want to avoid this warning in chrome and also do not want to change any setting of chrome like unchecking Safe browsing option

```
Code in Component.html file
<button class="download-link" (click)="downloadFile('/supportbundleDownload/20190710')">Click here to download the logs.</button>


Code in component.ts file
downloadFile(url:string) {
        var sequenceNumber = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length);
        this.SomeService.downloadFile(url).subscribe(response=> {
            var fileName = "logs_complete_" + sequenceNumber + ".tar.gz"
            var newBlob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/gzip" });
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob, fileName);
              }
            else {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
                a.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
              }
        })


Code in component.service.ts
downloadFile(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
        return this.http.get(url);
    }

The file is getting downloaded but chrome is blocking it and showing the warning. The file type is .tar.gz
```